# Zabbix. Math operations with items -> graph

Tags: zabbix

I am using [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) 1.8 for network management reporting.

I have an item, for example `net.if.in[<if><,mode>]`

I need to build graph using value `(net.if.in[<if><,mode>])/n`, where "n" is any integer.

I know just this way - in item's properties put a "multiplier" "1/n", but a think that is not true way :)

Help me please to find true way to do math operations with items and build a graph with it

Comment: This doesn't really make a lot of sense, and if it did I would expect it would be more suited to Stackoverflow than here, you may want to post something there.

Comment: :( sorry, my english is not very good

Comment: well per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zabbix this is network management so it's in the correct place..

Answer (score 1):

Your only real option here as you say is to use the multiplier value. But bare in mind that using a multiplier will pre-process data with your multiplier then store the result in the database, so make sure this is what you want before changing it.

If you want to keep the data as-is and transform it in graphs only, then you'll likely need to graph the data externally. Alternatively use another item to store the transformed data but this potentially doubles your disk space requirements.

Answer (score 1):

1. if you don't need the data elsewhere, just use the multiplier
2. if you do need the original data elsewhere, since zabbix version 1.8.1 you can create another item of type "calculated" and then graph that - for more details see http://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/manual/config/items#calculated_items

Answer (score -1):

Also [zabbix forum](http://www.zabbix.com/forum/) is a good place to ask such question. They are pretty helpful there.